# handle swipe gesture listener for item ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to know what's the proper way to define swipe gesture listener for recyclerView item ViewHolder. Here is what is did:

1. Define the Click Listener Interface

```
    interface StockItemViewClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(stock: Stock)
    
        fun onItemLongClick(stock: Stock)
    
        fun onGestureListener(stock: Stock)
    }
```

2. my activity class implements above interface, and then pass `this` when creating recycler adapter

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), StockItemViewClickListener {
         // some code here ...
    }
```

3. Last, do something inside ViewHolder Class

```
    class StockViewHolder(
       private val view: View,
       private val itemClickListener: StockItemViewClickListener
     ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
         view.setOnClickListener {
            stock?.let {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(it)
            }
        }
          view.setOnLongClickListener {
            stock?.let {
                itemClickListener.onItemLongClick(stock)
            }
            true
        }
        // some other code
    }
```

It was quite easy to define onItemClick and onItemLongClick, but I have no idea how to handle the gesture inside the ViewHolder.  I have read this article https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html but not sure how to correctly apply this into my code. Any help would be appreciate! pseudo code is enough!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener) to achieve what you want. Just add it to the `itemView` of your ViewHolder.